# How to scrape addresses from a web page for geocoding purposes?

Tags: geocoding

I am trying to get addresses from a [web page](http://www.phillypal.com/pal_locations.php) for mapping purposes. I know I could copy and paste the addresses into an Excel file and geocode them but I was wondering if there was any faster way to get the address from a web page and create a point location file?

Comment: It all depends on how the addresses are formatted on said web page, but yes parsing addressing into a .csv and then geocoding is quite possible.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping]). If that is the case, which isn't really a GIS question, consider asking the question over at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), or searching their tags [screen-scraping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-scraping) and [web-scraping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping).

Comment: as above, but it's fairly easy to write a small app that looks at a specific part of a web page and disemintaes the information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should get you started. Python and the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module to the rescue. The code below will print out a list of the 26 addresses on that webpage. I used Firebug in Firefox to look at the page source, which told me that the cell width was 37%. I gambled that those cells were maybe the only ones at 37% width, and was right. You should be able to feed the list of addresses you get into a online geocoder and get point locations.

[image]

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.phillypal.com/pal_locations.php'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html)

addresses = soup.findAll('td', {'width':'37%'})

print len(addresses)

for address in addresses:
    print address.find(text=True)
```